# Função não entra no sucesso do ajax com jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Não consigo entrar no sucesso do ajax com essa função. A função funciona, ou seja, chama o duplo clique. O primeiro alert está ok, mas o segundo não é disparado.

```
$('#nmUsuario').on("dblclick", '.clique', function() {

    alert('Alô, tudo bem?');

    var obj = {};

    $('tr').each(function () {
        obj = {
            _nivel: $(this).find('td').eq(0).text, 
            _nome: $(this).find('td').eq(1).text, 
            _usuario: $(this).find('td').eq(2).text
        }
    })

    $.ajax({

            url: '/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            data: obj,
            success: function(data){
                alert('Alô, tudo bem 1?');
            },
            error: function(error){
            }
        })
})
```

Fazendo meus testes, vi que isso está errado:

```
$('tr').each(function () {
        obj = {
            _nivel: $(this).find('td').eq(0).text, 
            _nome: $(this).find('td').eq(1).text, 
            _usuario: $(this).find('td').eq(2).text
        }
    })
```

Comment: A função de erro é chamada? Há várias formas de uma chamada ajax falhar, e sem saber o que o `/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina` faz fica difícil saber.

Comment: Uma outra coisa: você define o Content-Type como JSON, mas o dado é enviado como um objeto (que por default é serializado como dados de formulário). Troque o `data: obj` por `data: JSON.stringify(obj)`. E veja se a função de error é chamada com maiores informações sobre por que a de sucesso não é.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()`

O dataType pode ser JSON sem problemas.

Sua variável obj é um problema. Ela sempre irá conter os dados da última linha. Use:

```
var obj = [];
$('tr').each(function(index) {
   obj[index] = { ...... }
});
```

Comment: Não consigo passar o valor da <td> para minhas variáveis na controller.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo seu problema está aqui:

```
 url: '/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
```

Você precisa passar a url completa, exemplo:

```
 url: 'http://www.seusite.com.br/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
```

Certifique-se também que é retornado para essa função o tipo de dado que é passado no parametro `dataType`